# ESP8266 "AT" shows no response

Tags: serial-port, iot, at-command, esp8266, ftdi

I tried to communicate with my ESP8266 over a serial connection but i don't receive any response from the device.

What is working: Flashing works and i can get the Chip ID and MAC address (using esptool).

Wiring is done like shown here
[image]

Power comes from an external stable 3,3 V source. No VCC connection on the USB-Serial converter side (but they share a common GND connection). Changing the Baud-Rate makes no difference. I tried screen, minicom and Arduino's Serial Monitor. I can send "AT" but the response is empty. The monitor's window is full of rubbish when i grab the MAC address over esptool.

I'm pretty much out of ideas at the moment! What else can I try?

Comment: Are you sure your ESP runs the correct firmware? TX->RX and RX->TX connections are right? For it to *run* the firmware, you must not connect GPIO0 to GND, as this will cause the ESP to boot into "download new firmware" mode. Leave GPIO0 floating and do a power cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I firstly flashed the empty chip with the nodemcu firmware. I didn't get any response from the device. Seems to me, it doesn't include everything (at least no AT commands or i need to flash it with another firmware first). So I flashed the latest non SDK espressif Firmware under Windows. Chip boots up fine and i get 'Ready' in the console. Next thing is to figure out how to send and receive AT commands.